# Using vue-socket.io-extended, emit with vuex problem

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vuex, eslint

I have made a chat app with vue-cli for practice. I used vue-socket.io-extended as the plugin on client side for making socket-io connections.

I emit to server in vuex store so that I am able to connect to the socket inside any commonments.

Here is how I write the emit call in vuex actions:

```
actions: {
  emitSendMsg(dispatch, msgToSend){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._vm.$socket.client.emit('msg', msgToSend,(error)=>{
        if(error){
          return reject(error);
        }
        resolve();
      })        
    })
  }
}
```

and this is how I call the emit function in vue components methods:

```
methods:{
  sendMsg(){
    const self = this;
    if(!self.msgToSend){
      return alert('Please input mssage');
    }      
    self.disableCompose();
    self.$store.dispatch("emitSendMsg", self.msgToSend).then(() => {
      self.clearCompose();
    }).catch(function(error) {
      alert(error);
      self.clearCompose();
    });      
  }
}
```

As you can see, I used Promise so that the methods can do call-back actions.

Actually it works fine, the problem is, in the emit functions in vuex, I created a variable "dispatch" and I haven't actually used it, and I make me don't pass the rule "no-unused-vars" of es-lint and I can not commit my file to git unless I disable the rules.

I've tried the syntax below as the plug-in's npm page provided but it doesn't work.

```
actions: {
    emitSocketEvent(data) {
      this._vm.$socket.client.emit('eventName', data);
      this._vm.$socket.client.emit('with-binary', 1, '2', { 3: '4', 5: new Buffer(6) });
    }
  }
```

So is there any more proper way to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend the variable with underscore and [ignore it](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-unused-vars#ignore-identifiers-that-match-specific-patterns).

Or you could pass an empty object `emitSendMsg({}, msgToSend)`

Also, the object passed as first parameter to action is the `context` not `dispatch` and it is not optional.

If you need only `dispatch` you could use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) `emitSendMsg({ dispatch }, msgToSend)`

Comment: I've tried the empty object, it breaks the no-empty-pattern rules.
Should I use emitSendMsg(_context, msgToSend) instead?